# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i getting this error when inserting a record with "<".

how to solve this error with inserting a string with "<" in it. 
im using entity framework. this column has a datatype of nvarchar.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has been wrongly marked as duplicate, as this specific to MVC Version 4, and can have different types of solutions (specific to architecture and version).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try setting the attribute `requestValidationMode="2.0"` on the `<httpRuntime />` element in `web.config`

```
<system.web>
...
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
...
</system.web>
```

And decorate your controller/action (choose the apropriate one) with:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string s)
{
    ....
}
```

Note: Always sanitize your input.

Comment: when i use [ValidateInput(false)] the value of my object becomes null.

Comment: Can you update your question with sample input, and the controller action?

Comment: @scheien Thanks, i was struggling with the issue. Finally i was able to solve it. Thanks again..!!

Answer (score 8):

Apart from what @scheien already suggested you could check if you are setting the input (with potentialy dangerous script i.e. < character) to some model value that does not accept it. Try doing this:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string text{ get; set;}
```